# Как создать кастомное окно с "дырами" на PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, setmask

Нужно сделать кастомное окно с пустотой, при клике в которую (в пустоту) фокус получает то, что находится в этой **`"пустоте"`**.

Например, если в этом отверстии находится кнопка другого окна, то окно содержащее эту кнопку получает фокус и происходит нажатие на кнопку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример через setMask: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/9df8403930485408ca5c03a4a8cc3fa135cdf835/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QWidget_setMask__frameless_window/main.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [QWidget::setMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask) с чёрно-белым [QBitmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbitmap.html) или [QWidget::setMask](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-1) с [QRegion](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregion.html) из которого вырезать нужную область.

Answer (score 4):

А как вам такой вариант ?

```
import sys                                                         
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QStyle

class Invisible(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__press_pos = QPoint() 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)   
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setText("<b style='color:red'> Drag me :)  </b>")
        self.setFont(QFont("Times", 110)) 
        self.adjustSize()
        self.setGeometry(
            QStyle.alignedRect(
                Qt.LeftToRight,
                Qt.AlignCenter,
                self.size(),
                QApplication.instance().desktop().availableGeometry()
            )
        )

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__press_pos = event.pos()  

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.__press_pos = QPoint()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.__press_pos.isNull():  
            self.move(self.pos() + (event.pos() - self.__press_pos))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Invisible()
    w.show()
    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]